# Context menu in web applications, yay or nay?

Tags: language-agnostic

There have been a few things in web app's that I don't like. First and foremost is not having a right click context menu. I'm so used to right clicking on an item in a list and doing an action. So I've had a browse around, and it's certainly doable here's an [example](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/demos/jquery/vertical_menu.html).

My question is, are there reasons not to do this? I can't think of a single web site I've been to that uses a context menu like this. Is that just an historical convention, or is there something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its so much as historical convention, more than in order to catch the right-click event you basically have to override/ignore the web browser's default functionality for right-clicking.

That being said it absolutely can be done via Javascript - here is one example ( i haven't used this, but just did a quick Google search ):

http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm

Comment: Yep, the example in my post looks similar. I tend to agree, it would have to be selective. I wouldn't want to not be able to get at the right click browser menu at all. I get frustrated when I click in a Flash animation thinking it's a web page and expecting the browser right click. That's more frustrating because the Flash right click menu is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Context menus are an excellent tool for web applications. The issue is many Mac users are not used to right-clicking.

Comment: I'm a mac user, well I have a macbook in my arsenal of machines and that hadn't occured to me :) I don't think it's too much of an issue these days. Macbooks right click with two finger clicks and the new apple mice do two buttons even if they look one button. Plus, secretly I don't want to encourage their one button mouse nonsense any more ;)